# Command not found - installing ganache-cli with yarn on Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, installation, terminal, ganache

I've installed nodeJS in the terminal of Visual Studio version :

`v16.13.1`

Yarn

`1.22.17`

Ganache-cli

`MacBook:web3_py_simple_storage myName$ yarn global add ganache-cli`

````
warning ../package.json: No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Installed "ganache-cli@6.12.2" with binaries:
      - ganache-cli
✨  Done in 1.10s.```


BUT when I try to do `ganache-cli --version`, I always received the same msg `bash: ganache-cli: command not found`... I maybe think it's a path problem but I tried a lot and a lot of solution and still nothing.. 

I really thanks a lot in advance the guy who will help me !
````

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue earlier today, got it solved by typing this command in my visual studio terminal

**npm install -g ganache-cli**

(Note: You must have Nodejs already installed)
After the installation simply run the command below

**ganache-cli --version**
to check if it was installed properly

Answer (score 0):

I used `npm install -g ganache` and it solved my problem, but when I want to start Ganache-cli, run with `npx ganache-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to add it to path

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
```